# regExp weird reaction in Chrome console

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

as the following regExp:

```
var reg = /(\.[\u4e00-\u9fa5A-Z_])+/i;
reg.test('.a.s');
```

only the Chrome get false, other browsers and node all get true.

[image]

Is that because the Chrome regExp engine?

---

This problem was solved thanks to the anser of @Wiktor Stribiżew. Please refer to his answer.

======================================================================

This may be a bug of ES6 when perform RegExp. Someone has report the issue in both node and chrome community. Refer to these:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/7708?plg_nld=1&plg_uin=1&plg_auth=1&plg_nld=1&plg_usr=1&plg_vkey=1&plg_dev=1

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=5199

Comment: However, `/(\.[\u{4e00}-\u{9fa5}A-Z_])+/iu.test('.a.s')` works. Chrome engine is ES6 compliant.

Answer (score 3):

Latest Chrome versions run on V8 that is ES6 compliant.

So, the `\u9fa5A` is treated as one code point rather than `\u9fa5` and `A`, see this test:

```js
 // Chorme 51.0.2704.103 m output is given on the right
console.log(
  String.fromCharCode(parseInt("4e00", 16)), //  => "一"
  String.fromCharCode(parseInt("9fa5A", 16)), // => "署"
  String.fromCharCode(parseInt("9fa5", 16)) //  =>  "龥"
);
```

You need to make sure the `\u` values are parsed correctly with `\u{XXXX}` notation and `/u` modifier (will work with ES6 only) or rearrange the character class parts as shown below:

```js
console.log(/(\.[\u{4e00}-\u{9fa5}A-Z_])+/iu.test('.a.s'));
// or rearrange the ranges:
console.log(/(\.[A-Z_\u4e00-\u9fa5])+/i.test('.a.s'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. 

 It turns out I am using the latest version of Chrome 51.  
 It is like what you said, I test it on node (version 6,1) also got the same result.

Comment: Just FYI: if you do not find a match in `.a.5`, add `^` at the start of the pattern and `$` at its end.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked with the result. I have got only true result. Do you have any particular version or something?

[image: I am getting the true result only]

Comment: I can repro the OP issue in Chrome 51.0.2704.103 m

Comment: In Chrome Version 48.0.2564.116 gives true.

Comment: my Chrome version is 51,and  as I tested Chrome 49 is normal.

please refer to  @Wiktor Stribiżew has given a perfect answer